# How to auto fill SlugField instead of overriding save()?

Tags: django, django-models

**Hello Awesome People**

I wonder if there is a way to generate slug, rather than overriding the `save()` methods of my models.
Here's how I used to do:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.pk is None:
        self.slug = create_slug(self)
    super(ModelName, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

`create_slug` is a function that generates the slug with `slugify`

```
def create_slug(instance,new_slug=None,field="name"):
    ''' long stuff to ensure the slug is unique '''
    return slug
```

As django can do in Django Admin by automatically filling the slug field. Possible that we can simply add
an additional argument `models.SlugField(field='name')`. by adding this argument, django will make sure to take the value of `field = name` before saving to generate the slug without always overriding the `save()` method by copy/paste a lot of code to generate a slug for each model that We have.

I'm a little tired of copying this for all models, any hint will help!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no such argument on model level. You can do it on admin level using [`prepopulated_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.prepopulated_fields):

```
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ("title",)}
```

On the model level you can write custom mixin class and use it as parent for all models:

```
class SlugMixin:
    def create_slug(instance,new_slug=None,field="name"):
        ''' long stuff to ensure the slug is unique '''
        return slug

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.pk is None:
            self.slug = create_slug(self)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

class SomeModel(SlugMixin, models.Model):
    ...

class OtherModel(SlugMixin, models.Model):
    ...
```

In this case you don't need to implement `create_slug` and override `save` in each models.

Comment: this is a great answer, but there's no difference between `super(ModelName, self)` and `super().save(*args, **kwargs)`? I see that you remove `ModelName,self`

Comment: @EuChi in Python3 you dont need Class and instance arguments for super method. You can use `super()` directly. This arguments are required for Python2 only.

Comment: Awesome! thank you. This will anticipate a lot of work

Comment: Most likely [django.utils.text.slugify](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.text.slugify) will come in handy.